# Blob Url obtained from URL.createObjectUrl(mediastream) returns HTTP 404

Tags: javascript, blob, mediastream

I'm trying to get a MediaStream object into a blob, but I have some problems.

This is the part of my script for the `UserMedia` component:

```
var mediastream = undefined;
var blob = undefined;
var video = document.getElementById('test');
```

This is my script where I'm trying my test:

```
var mediastream = undefined;
var blobUrl = undefined;
var video = document.getElementById('test');
function successCallback (stream) {

    mediastream = stream;
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mediastream);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', blobUrl, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log('xhr.readyState='+xhr.readyState);
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    } else {
        var myBlob = this.response;
    }

function errorCallback (stream) {
    console.log('error');
}
```

Setting the blobUrl to the video.src I don't have any problem:
`video.src = blobUrl;`  <-  WORKS

But if I call the urlBob url (like this one: `blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/b1ffa5b7-c0cc-4acf-8890-f5d0f08de9cb` ) I obtain HTTP status 404.

For sure there is something wrong on my implementation. 
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “calling the URL”?

Comment: I mean that I have 404 in this line:   xhr.open('GET', blobUrl, true);